# Is there any TTS library that can be used in STM32

Tags: embedded, text-to-speech, gsm, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide

I am working on a project that involves the conversion of dynamic text to speech. I need to call a specific number and play this speech using a GSM module. I am using the STM32F407G-DISC BOARD. The IDE I am using is STM32CubeIDE. I was unable to find an appropriate library to convert text to speech.

I tried using eSpeak NG library .But the size of this library is very large and also it have portability issue. I am expecting a library that is compactable with STM32.

Comment: Unambiguously off topic question.  Didn't take much Google Fu though to find https://github.com/Bakisha/STM32SAM (demoed at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov32R0B__6Y)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.